# Only require textfield when radio is selected. ZF2

Tags: forms, zend-framework2

In ZF2, is it possible to require a textfield only when a radio button is selected? like so..

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, There is no way in ZF2 for this, You can use jQuery of javascript to add the validation for this:

Like this:

```
$('radio').click(function(){
  if($(this).val() == 'other') {
     $('textfield').prop('required',true);
  }
});
```

`Onclick`  on any radio button a client side event and zf2 runs on server side. So you cann't do this untill you are submitting the data to server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JavaScript library jQuery to do this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#Radiobuttons").click(function() {
       if($(this).attr('id') == "Other") {
            //IF THE ID IS "OTHER"
            $("#foo").show();           
       }  else {
            //IF THE ID IS NOT "OTHER"
            $("#foo").hide();   
       }
   });
});
```

Because with just this, the user can submit the form with the text box empty, and the check box ticked, you can use this script.

```
//CHECK IF THE FORM IS SUBMITTED
if ( $("#foo").css('display') != 'none' ){
    //The text box is visible. Now check if it's empty, with
    //jQuery, PHP, or any other thing you use.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i'm already using this. But then it's possible to post the form while the radio is selected and the textfield is empty. And when i always require the textfield then i get an errors that it's empty while it's hidden. do you understand my predicament?

Comment: @user3481441 I am pretty sure that you can check if an element is hidden, in jQuery. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is pretty old, though maybe someone will make use of it. 
There **is** a way to do that.

In the form class remove inputFilter method from the __construct. Then in your inputFilter method (lets name it addInputFilter) add paramater like this:

```
public function addInputFilter(array $data) {

$inputFilter = new InputFilter();
$this->setInputFilter($inputFilter)


//your inputfilters

if ($data['radiofield'] === 'something') { 
    //add next inputfilters 
} 

//your inputfilters

}
```

Next, go to the place where you call the form (controller probably?):

```
$data = $this->request->getPost();

$form->setInputFilter($form->addInputFilter($data->toArray()));
$form->setData($data);

// next check if form is valid etc.
```

Thats all.